# how to fix error: inject() must be called from an injection context while using Auth0/angular-jwt?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, auth0

I am using angular 15.0 and installed @auth0/angular-jwt. the App.Module has configured as follows:

```js
import {HttpClientModule} from "@angular/common/http";
import { JwtModule } from "@auth0/angular-jwt";

export function tokenGetter() {
  return localStorage.getItem("jwt");
}
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ....
    HttpClientModule,
    ...
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config:{
        tokenGetter: tokenGetter,
        whitelistedDomains: ["localhost:5001"],
        blacklistedRoutes: []
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [
 ....
  ],
  exports: [
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
  constructor(library: FaIconLibrary) {
    library.addIconPacks(far, fab);
  }
}
```

at first, when I imported the JWTModule, I got warnning that: `Argument type {config: {tokenGetter: () => string | null, blacklistedRoutes: any[], whitelistedDomains: string[]}} is not assignable to parameter type Routes`  but no error!. so far, when I run the app, no pages is loaded and in the console this error is rised: `NG0203: inject() must be called from an injection context such as a constructor, a factory function, a field initializer, or a function used with EnvironmentInjector#runInContext`.I found that this error is only for importing JwtModule and when I remove this, the main page of app is loaded and everything is normal. also, I created an AuthGuard service, I haven't used it yet, Because I assumed that the above error should be resolved first. the snippet code for service is:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ActivatedRouteSnapshot, CanActivate, Router, RouterStateSnapshot} from "@angular/router";
import { JwtHelperService } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private router:Router, private jwtHelper: JwtHelperService){}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem("jwt");
    if (token && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)){
      return true;
    }
    this.router.navigate(["login"]);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Thank you for your guidance on the correct use of the JwtModule of the Auth0/angular-jwt.

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace?

Comment: No, I just use browser inspect and set the break points to debug and trace

Comment: But, I use jetbrains webstorm, is it possible use stacktrace in the webstorm, and how?